# Visual Studio 2010 says “Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct”

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When trying to write something to check whether a number is odd or even (C#), Visual Studio 2010 displays the error message I've mentioned above...
This is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void chk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(num.Text);
            if (x%2 == 0)
            {
                chkd.Text = "Even";
            }
            else
            {
                chkd.Text = "Odd";
            }
        }
    }

    private void num_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Posting the *actual* code instead of a screenshot would be most helpful. By my count, line 29 isn't even in that screenshot.

Comment: It *looks* like you're missing a closing curly brace (`}`) at the end of your `Form1.cs`. Check the last `}` of the file and see if it has a red squiggly, and try adding another one. Another good way to check your compilation errors is to double-click the error, and it will take you to the line of code that is problematic. As @GlorinOakenfoot has mentioned, it's better to post the actual code in the first place, rather than a screenshot

Comment: Double click the error to show you which line it is on, I don't think it's on the screenshot - it's probably further down.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and go to Tools--> options --> Text Editor --> All Languages --> and click the "line numbers" checkbox.  Then when an error points to a specific line number, you can see exactly where that is.  On a side note, why isn't this turned on by default?

Comment: @Charles Mager, thanks, but how?

Answer (score 2):

`num_TextChanged` is a method that is outside your class.  The only things that can appear inside a namespace scope are, per the error message, a class, delegate, enum, interface or struct.

I expect you meant this to be inside the `Form1` class, so you should move it:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void chk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(num.Text);
            if (x%2 == 0)
            {
                chkd.Text = "Even";
            }
            else
            {
                chkd.Text = "Odd";
            }
        }

        private void num_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You meant that I should remove it? I did so, but then I got this "Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'num_TextChanged' and no extension method 'num_TextChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: No, *move* it,  As your new error implies, there is something expecting that event handler to exist in `Form1`.

Comment: What did you mean by _move_?

Comment: I'm not sure how explain move in another way. I mean take it from where it was and put it somewhere else (inside `Form1` in this case). Your code is in the question and my (fixed) code is in the answer. Can't you see what I've changed?

Comment: ohh!! thanks man, and could you explain further about the mistake?

Comment: What part of the explanation isn't clear? The method should belong to the class and you'd somehow moved it outside that scope. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more
    }

which close /end namespace of form class

Comment: You maybe right, but isn't it better to be able to see the actual code before making assumptions?

Comment: Adding one more } leads for Visual Studio to say   Error 2 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected....  but double clicking the error highlights the 'void' of "private void num_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)" which is below that chk_click codes....                    btw, how to post the coding?

Comment: To post your code - Highlight the code of your file. Copy the code (right-click > Copy). Paste the code in your OP (right-click > Paste). Save your answer.